# Changing height in TikZ-UML of umlstate title

Tags: height, tikz-uml

I am trying to draw a UML state diagram with `tikz-uml` and can't find a way to change the size of the text field for every state.

When I am creating two states like one with the name *Tf* and another called *Gg* the height of the text field in state *Gg* will be greater because of the *g*:

[image: different size of states]

Is there any way to define a fix height or another tool where I can create UML diagrams with the TeX font?

I used `\umlbasicstate[]{}` and `\begin{umlstate}[]{}\end{umlstate}` both with arguments like `text height`, `minimum height` or `minimum size` but nothing works. :-(

Comment: Maybe the vphantom command is helpful here. Just search the site for it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the node in question is set with no styles at all, or only `above`, which makes it a bit trickier. None of the options passed to `umlstate` will be applied.  One option I found is to use `xpatch` to insert a `\strut` into the definition of `\tikzumlState@caption`, which is a macro where the text of that node is stored.

[image: code output]

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\umlstate}{\def\tikzumlState@caption{#2}}{\def\tikzumlState@caption{#2\strut}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{umlstate}{a}
\end{umlstate}
\begin{umlstate}[x=1.8,y=-0.08]{Ag}
\end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```